# How to decide range of a quadratic form under constraint condition?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Is there any easy way to decide range of $x_1^2 - 2x_2^2 + x_3^2 + 2{x_1}{x_2} - 4{x_1}{x_3} + 2{x_2}{x_3}$ under $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = 1$? I tried with calculus and found it a bit difficult. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Your quadratic form is associated with the symmetric matrix
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -2 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ -2 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
whose eigenvalues are $-3,3$ and $0$; the corresponding eigenvectors are $(1,-2,1)^T,(-1,0,1)^T,(1,1,1)^T$. Through a suitable change of base, your problem is equivalent to understanding what is the range of $-3z_1^2+3z_2^2$ under the constraint $z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2=1$, but that range is obviously $[-3,3]$.